# Сортировка записей на сайте

Tags: php, сортировка

```
SORT BY id DESC
```

Как применить эту сортировку в этом коде?

```
 <?php
$singles = get_singles_all();  //Здесь я запускаю цикл что бы мне выводилась 
информация хранящаяся в phpMyAdmin

foreach ($singles as $single): ?> <!--Здесь я разложил массив singles на массив single-->

<?php $category = get_category_by_id ($single["category_id"]); ?>
<?php $author = get_author_by_id ($single["author_id"]); ?>

<a href="fullSingle.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"]; ?>" class="href_single active_href_single">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div class="img-responsive">
            <div class="imgBorder">
                 <img src="<?php echo $single["img"]; ?>" class="img"> 
            </div>

            <div class="singleBorder">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <h4 class="wordSingle"><?php echo $single["title"]; ?></h4>                                                     <!--Заголовок-->
                <p class="textSingle text-left"><?php echo $string = mb_substr($single["text"], 0, 190).'...'; ?>               <!--Текст поста-->
                <a href="fullSingle.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"]; ?>">Показать полностью</a></p><br/>                        <!--Ссылка на полный пост-->
                <span class="dateSingle">Дата публикации: <?php echo date("d.m.Y в H:i", strtotime($single["date"])); ?></span> <!--Дата публикации поста-->
                <p class="category">Категория: <?php echo $category["category_name"]; ?></p>                                    <!--Имя категории-->
                <p class="author">Автор статьи: <?php echo $author["author_name"]; ?></p>                                       <!--Имя автора-->
                <span class="comments">Комментариев: <?php echo $single["comments"]; ?></span>                                  <!--Число коментариев-->
                <span class="views">Просмотры: <?php echo $single["views"]; ?></span>                                           <!--Число просмотров-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Если нужно могу запостить сами функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать это с помощью PHP, вам понадобится применить функцию `krsort`, в официальной документации показывается, как `bool krsort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )` .

всё, что нужно сделать - передать массив в эту функцию. Она отсортирует его. Пример: `krsort($singles)`

Если вы хотите узнать об этой функции более подробно, [Вот статья из официальной документации о ней](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.krsort.php).

[Другие функции для сортировки массива тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.